# How to use one table rows (in like operator) as the parameter for another table in a function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to use one table rows (in like operator) as the parameter for another table in a function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Give specific details on what you're trying to accomplish and the attempts done by you to achieve the result.

Comment: I have a table storing table constants for example tempb, tempc, tempa and another table storing tempb1, tempb2, tempb3,tempa_1, tempa_2 and tempa_3. both are storing multiple rows. I want to send first table values to the second table as a parameter in a function or cursor.

Comment: @Sanjana please [edit] any new information directly into the question.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you mean.

`DECLARE @text varchar(50) = (SELECT Value FROM TABLE WHERE Value like '%descriptor%')`

Comment: I have a table storing table constants for example tempb, tempc, tempa and another table storing tempb1, tempb2, tempb3,tempa_1, tempa_2 and tempa_3. both are storing multiple rows. I want to send first table values to the second table as a parameter in a function or cursor.